# Core Plot: Issue with plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo and autoscaling of y-axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I have upgraded from CorePlot 1.1 to CorePlot 1.4 and experience a issue with `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo`: Core Plot does not  scale the y-axis correctly.

Do I have to change anything in my code? (My code worked perfectly before upgrading to CorePlot 1.4).

Could there be a bug in Core Plot?
My issue looks familiar to this issue reported here: [Core Plot Issue 594](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=594&sort=-id)
(I am using `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo` in my code, disabling this method helps)

Comment: I'd tried to remove default plot space and then create new CPTXYPlotSpace and add it to graph.

Comment: scale 0..1 often happens when there is no data in dataSource or no plots in plot space

Comment: I have disabled `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo` and it works. I am looking for a solution on how to get it working and have `plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo` activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CPTXYPlotSpace` changed in release 1.4. It now calls the `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` delegate method any time the x- or y-range changes, not just when scrolling or zooming. You will need to adjust the delegate to account for this, or simply set the delegate after doing the initial plot space setup.